# java webstart application startup time too slow

Tags: java, performance, java-web-start

I have a java webstart application with many dependency jars(about 20), it starts up quickly in the development environment as a standalone app.  However when it's deployed in java webstart, the start up time is slow(1 minute or so).  Is there a way to improve the startup time?

Comment: Are you sure you need all those jar files? More often than not , I find that people bundle a whole load of unnecessary jar files that slow down the application.

Answer (score 4):

Try this if you are starting Java Web Start app from Windows XP or Windows 7.

Go to java control panel. Under "General" tab open "Network Settings" and choose **"Direct connection"** instead of "Use browser settings".

"User browser settings" is the default on fresh java install.

When I was using java web start (I didn't look into why), this made it launch 5 to 10 times faster. Tested on couple Windows XP and Windows 7 using both Java 6 and Java 7.