# speed up cached webstart launch

Tags: performance, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a large Webstart application (due to using Eclipse RCP and a lot of dependencies) which uses 138 jars.

From my IDE (on a very fast machine) the application starts in 7.5s but from Webstart (cached without an update) it takes an additional 2.5s to a total of 10s. (Which used to be 13.5s before I disabled using browser proxy as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149011/java-webstart-application-startup-time-too-slow))

Is there a way I can further speed this up? I already tried setting the update check to background and using the "Version Download Protocol" but this doesn't seem to help (saves at most 0.5s).

I suspect jar signer verification to be the culprit of this extra time so I'm afraid this is impossible. (I also had to solve many many other Webstart issues, in retrospect I should probably not have used Webstart at all but create my own installer.)

Comment: Are you using tomcat to deploy you web app ?

Comment: No, I'm using Jetty embedded in my server application.

Comment: Change the logging level to DEBUG in jetty and see if that reveals anything interesting. If nothing else, it might allow you to narrow down where in the startup sequence the problem is. - Refer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398268/jetty-startup-delay)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have been also running the application offline. Between running offline and online there is no noticeable difference in startup time (< 0.5s). I turned on debugging and I can confirm that the Jetty webserver is not contacted at all when running the application offline (and it IS when running the application online).